# React stripe publishable key is empty error is coming

Tags: reactjs, redux, stripe-payments, react-state

currently i am integrating stripe.js with react and 
 stripe publishable key is coming from backend API(spring boot). 
so, i need to attach publishable key dynamically returned from API response.

so, for that first i am storing publishable key into my redux-store and then trying to set it from redux but it gives me below error in my browser console when stripe checkout component is loaded.

Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Please call Stripe() with your publishable key. You used an empty string.

below is my react code

```
const Checkout = (props) => {
  const publishableKey = useSelector((state) => state.payment.publishableKey);

  const stripePromise = loadStripe(
    publishableKey
  );

  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <CheckoutChild />
    </Elements>
  );
};
export default Checkout;
```

Comment: Can you add logging of the `publishableKey` prior to calling `loadStrip()`?  The first place to look is whether the error message is correct and `state.payment.publishableKey` is not returning the correct value.

Comment: first time when component is loaded then values of publishableKey is undefined. at that time error is coming. but as soon as response from backend arrives this component is loaded again and value for publishableKey is set.